# Flutter firebase_auth package does not provide "refresh token" property

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, refresh-token

I need to get refresh token from firebase auth, which I will use that "refresh token" for custom backend API. But firebase_auth plugin "getIdToken" class, I use parameter "refresh" and set as "true" it is just returning a refreshed JWT idToken, But what I want is a "refresh token". Is there an alternative solution for this issue?[This is the link for issue I posted on github.](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/52933)

I have posted this issue on github as well, if there is any solution, kindly share your advice. Thank you in advance.